# Node async modify current object

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I'm having problem in getting current object of array in async series function. In following code i want to show then current person in timeout function. Kindly suggest me how could i get current person so that i could make my desired changes in that object. At the end in callback function what i want to do is to get updated objects array.

```
async.series({
    personName: function (callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //In following line show Current Person in console.
            console.log(People.Person);

            callback(null, People.Person);
        }, 200);
    }
}, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: What is the problem here? I get the value properly. Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @thefourtheye yeah bro there is no issue in code. It was just my understanding issue.